# capture group negative lookahead ignored by regex

Tags: regex

In a long text file there are several headers.
I need to split this file so that I have each header and content separately.
Repeated headers are to be considered as one.
Minimum example:

```
HeaderA
example text

HeaderB
example text

HeaderC
example text

HeaderC
example text

HeaderD
example text
```

Using this regular expression in python I have managed that:

```
Header(\w)[\s\S]*?(?=Header(?!\1)|$)
```

note that both HeaderC are captured as one group.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dzaeg4/1)

Now I received a slightly altered text file that looks like this:

```
Header
foo
bar ID 1
foo

Header
foo 
bar ID 2
foo

Header
foo 
bar ID 3
foo

Header
foo 
bar ID 3
foo

Header
foo 
bar ID 4
foo
```

I tried altering my original expression for this example into this:

```
Header[\s\S]*?ID\s(\d)[\s\S]*?(?=Header[\s\S]*?ID\s(?!\1)|$)
```

[DEMO2](https://regex101.com/r/mmMHZo/1)

However I can't get this to work using the same technique as in my first example.

my desired result is that

```
Header
foo 
bar ID 3
foo

Header
foo 
bar ID 3
foo
```

is one match, similar to the first demo.
Any explanation as to what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated.
A working counterexample would also be accepted.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
(?s)Header.*?ID\s(\d).*?(?=Header(?!.*?ID\s(?=\1))|$)
Header[\w\W]*?ID\s(\d)[\w\W]*?(?=Header(?![\w\W]*?ID\s(?=\1))|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UtZgAp/1). The point here is to match up to the `Header` string that is not followed with any text, `ID`, whitespace not followed with the same number as in Group 1. In this case, the `.*?`/`[\w\W]*?`/`[\s\S]*?` gets expanded until the `Header` that contains a different number.

*Note*: `(?s)` is a DOTALL inline modifier that lets `.` match line break chars.

Here is how your regex matches first Header 3:

[image]

Here is my regex Header 3 match:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the demo.
I adapted it from the minimum example to the real thing and it does indeed work.